# how to remove content inside bracket without removing brackets

Tags: python, regex, string

```
string="file()(function)(hii)out(return)(byee)"
```

for this string i need output like

```
file()()()out()()
```

I have tried this

```
string="file()(function)(hii)out(return)(byee)"
string1=re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", string)
string2=re.sub(r" ?\([^)]+\)", "", string)

print(string1)
print(string2)
```

and got output like

```
fileout

file()out
```

my desired output should look like this:

```
file()()()out()()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use regex: capture all between Parentheses, i.e. **(.*?)** and replace it with an empty string i.e. **( )**

```
import re

x = "file()(function)(hii)out(return)(byee)"
x = re.sub("\(.*?\)", "()", x)
print(x)
```

this will print

> file()()()out()()